# HTTP Client Bad Request 400

Tags: http, netbeans, get, httpclient, bad-request

I am trying to learn about how a HTTP client works in Java. I am trying to build my own client that will make a request to a web server for a php file.

Currently when I make the request the server gives me the following error:

**HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**

However, I am able to access the file from within a browser no problem. I don't know what I could be doing wrong but I can't figure it out. Below is the code for my HTTP Client class:

```
public class MyHttpClient {

MyHttpRequest request;
String host;

public MyHttpResponse execute(MyHttpRequest request) throws IOException {

    //Creating the response object
    MyHttpResponse response = new MyHttpResponse();

    //Get web server host and port from request.
    String host = request.getHost();
    int port = request.getPort();

    //Check 1: HOST AND PORT NAME CORRECT!
    System.out.println("host: " + host + " port: " + String.valueOf(port));

    //Get resource path on web server from requests.
    String path = request.getPath();

    //Check 2: ENSURE PATH IS CORRECT!
    System.out.println("path: " + path);

    //Open connection to the web server
    Socket s = new Socket(host, port);

    //Get Socket input stream and wrap it in Buffered Reader so it can be read line by line.
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

    //Get Socket output stream and wrap it in a Buffered Writer so it can be written to line by line.
    PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);

    //Get request method
    String method = request.getMethod();

    //Check 3: ENSURE REQUEST IS CORRECT GET/POST!
    System.out.println("Method: " + method);

    //GET REQUEST
    if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){
        //Send request to server
        outToServer.println("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1 " + "\r\n");
        String line = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("Line: " + line);
    }

    //Returning the response
    return response;
}
```

}

If anyone could shed some light on this issue I'd appreciate it very much! Thanks.

New Request To Server:

```
outToServer.print("GET " + path+ " HTTP/1.1" + "\r\n");
outToServer.print("Host: " + host + "\r\n");
outToServer.print("\r\n");
```

Response:

Method: GET

```
line: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
line: <html><head>
line: <title>400 Bad Request</title>
line: </head><body>
line: <h1>Bad Request</h1>
line: <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
line: </p>
line: <hr>
line: <address>Apache Server at default.secureserver.net Port 80</address>
line: </body></html>
line: null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use PrintWriter. You have to write ascii characters.

```
 s.getOutputStream().write(("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n").getBytes("ASCII"));
```

Comment: Sorry, missed the method - write

Comment: FIXED!! Thank you so much! I've been working on this all day.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need at least to add the `Host` header in the request.

Example taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

After the headers are complete you also need to transfer an extra `\r\n` so the server knows that the request is complete.

Do not use `println` but `print`. `println` adds another `\n` to every line causing the lines to be terminated with `\r\n\n`.

Comment: I adjusted the request as you mentioned like this: `outToServer.println("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1 " + "\r\n");
            outToServer.println("Host: " + host);
            outToServer.println("\r\n");` but still getting error.

Comment: You forgot another `\r\n`. The host header is terminated by a `\r\n` and then the header block must be terminated by a `\r\n`.

Comment: Thank you it is working now but the first line I get back is not the status code? Is that normal? I was expecting something like GET 200 OK instead I get html

Comment: Do not use "println" but use "print". Println adds another `\n` so you end up with `\r\n\n` which probably causes the error.

Comment: I guess the server is reading your request as HTTP/0.9 request. HTTP/0.9 responses do not necessarily include headers.

Comment: I made the changes, I included them in my original question at the bottom. For some reason my program seems to hang for a long period of time and recieves no response from the server.

Comment: Make sure to call flush() once you are done sending your request: [PrintStream.flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush\(\))

Comment: oh ok, I am calling now and getting some sort of response which is good news! I included it in original question. Maybe your right when you say the server might be misinterpreting the requests.

Comment: Aww, I missed that you were using a PrintWriter. You should not need to work with the raw OutputStream though. Could you try passing a third argument to the PrintWriter constructor: `new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true, "ASCII")`. `UTF-8` instead of `ASCII` should work, too.

Comment: I will try that later on! Thank you.